# Running into an issue with tensorboard returning "tensorboard: error: unrecognized arguments:"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I want to call `tensorboard -- logdir = 'logs'` in the terminal but I get an error saying tensorboard: error: unrecognized arguments: -- logdir = 'logs'

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out: I need `tensorboard -- logdir = '/logs'`

Comment: `tensorboard -- logdir /logs` works as well

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces in your log path or change them like " " to "\ "
example: new folder ---->   new\ folder